# Is there a way to tell openmp that shared data is constant?

Tags: c++, memory-management, constants, openmp, shared

I am guessing that even reading from shared data in openmp causes some parallel overheads, as depending on processor architecture (if different cores have their own cache...) it may be necessary to refresh the cache to ensure that no other cpu has modified the data before reading.

Am I right in thinking this?

If so, is there a way to tell openmp (on the intel compiler fwiw) that some of the shared data is constant, so such cache refreshing isn't necessary?

If the answer is c++ `const` is there an easy way to turn non-const data into const data, without actually reallocating the memory, once the program has passed a certain point at runtime?

UPDATE

Ah, ok.  I now remember where I got my impression that `const` was a good thing in this context:  http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/cpumemory.pdf , section 6.4.1.  It's to do with false sharing, where readonly variables which share cache lines with readwrite variables incur the penalty of the cache line being marked exclusive by the readwrite variable.  The linked document recommends, for example with gcc, to mark those vars as `__attribute__((section(something.else)))` to ensure they get stored elsewhere.

As it happens this is not relevant in my own situation - large arrays and stl containers of data in which the read/write granularity will span many cache lines and which are allocated from different memory pools in any case.  So these will naturally be located on different cache lines.  No problem!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sharing read-only data among multiple cores has no overhead. The same copy of the data will be in the cache for all the cores that are using it.

The only time you will incur overhead is when one of the cores writes to the shared data. In that situation, you will incur a (potentially large) overhead because the write will invalidate all the other copies of that cache line and force them to grab it from memory or from a different cache.

In other words, the cache is only "refreshed" when somebody changes the data. There's no periodic "refreshing".

So the answer to your question is: You do not have to do anything. There's no way to tell OpenMP or the hardware that the data is constant and `const` will have no effect aside from syntax.

Comment: I think you are correct.  See my update to question to explain where the confusion came from in the first place (false sharing).

Answer (score 10):

I was also looking at this topic and found a general performance recommendation from Oracle:

> If a SHARED variable in a parallel region is read by the threads
>   executing the region, but not written to by any of the threads, then
>   specify that variable to be FIRSTPRIVATE instead of SHARED. This
>   avoids accessing the variable by dereferencing a pointer, and avoids
>   cache conflicts.

[Oracle OpenMP API User's Guide - Chapter 7 - Performance Considerations](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19059-01/stud.10/819-0501/7_tuning.html)

Answer (score 1):

`const` does not imply that the memory is constant. It implies that your handle to that memory cannot write to it (which is subtly different):

```
int i = 3;
int const& j = i;

i = 4;
std::cout << j << "\n";
```

Will print `4`, even though when `j` was bounded to `i` the value was `3`.

Therefore, `const` can only tell that *you* should not modify the underlying data (and the compiler will enforce it, to a point). It does not tell anything about the data itself, except when directly applied to the data:

```
char const array[] = "Some value";
```

Here the storage is `const`, the value is immutable, and the compiler is free to place this in ROM.